# Determinant of the matrix $(\omega^i \theta^j)_{i,j = 0,1,2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $\omega=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$  is a complex cube root of 1, $\theta$ is a real cube root of 2 and $\omega^{2}+\omega+1=0$, I am trying to maipulate the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \theta &\theta^{2} \\
\omega & \omega \theta & \omega \theta^{2} \\
\omega^{2} & \omega^{2}\theta & \omega^{2}\theta^{2}
\end{pmatrix}

to end up at

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \theta &\theta^{2} \\
1 & \omega \theta & \omega^{2}\theta^{2}  \\
1 & \omega^{2}\theta & \omega \theta^{2}
\end{pmatrix}

However I am struggling to come up with a way of manipulating the matrix in order to end up here.

Comment: what kind of manipulation$?$Are you trying to get the determinant of this matrix$?$

Comment: @emonHR I am trying to use row and column operations to arrive at the second matrix in order to then calculate the determinant.

Comment: Your first matrix rather obviously has determinant zero. Are you sure that's the matrix you are really interested in?

Comment: you have done so far. use the first leading $1$ to eliminate other then use this column to find out determinant.

Comment: I got the matrix from trying to calculate the discriminant of the basis $\{1,\theta,\theta^{2}\}$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ I may be wrong.

Comment: you want to end up with a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \theta &\theta^{2} \\
\omega & \omega \theta & \omega \theta^{2} \\
\omega^{2} & \omega^{2}\theta & \omega^{2}\theta^{2}
\end{vmatrix}
=\omega\,\omega^2\theta\,\theta^2\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1&1\\
1&1& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$$

The values of $\theta$ and $\omega$ don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: your original matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega\\\omega^2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 & \theta & \theta^2\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

From properties of determinants we get, by adding row 2 and row 3 to the first row
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \theta &\theta^{2} \\
\omega & \omega \theta & \omega \theta^{2} \\
\omega^{2} & \omega^{2}\theta & \omega^{2}\theta^{2}
\end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}
1+\omega+\omega^2 & \theta+\omega\theta+\omega^2\theta &\theta^{2}+\omega\theta^2+\omega^2\theta^2 \\
\omega & \omega \theta & \omega \theta^{2} \\
\omega^{2} & \omega^{2}\theta & \omega^{2}\theta^{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
The last matrix has a row of zeros, since $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.

Comment: This is overkill. Just notice that the rows or columns are linearly dependent.